# Find position of an item in RecyclerView from the data list

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to get the position of an item in `RecyclerView` from the dataset of the `RecyclerView`. Each of the item in my dataset contains a **unique id**. I want to find the adapter position of the item in the `RecyclerView` corresponding to an id in the dataset.

My dataset class looks like the following.

```
class dataset {
    int id;
    JSONArray linked;
    int type;
    ....
}
```

I add `TextView` or `EditText` to the `RecyclerView` according to the type.

Final aim: My `RecyclerView` can have multiple `EditText` and `TextViews` which are independent (although the `TextView` will have a field which has the id of the `EditText` it is linked to). When I click `TextView`, I will be having the id of `EditText`(dataset) to take data from. I want to get the text from corresponding `EditText` from the item in the `RecyclerView` with those id. If I can get the adapter position from the dataset, somehow I can use

```
recyclerview.getChildAt(position);
```

But there is no way to get the adapter position from data set.

Comment: dataset you mean from the list??

Comment: @SantanuSur Yes

Comment: yes just loop through the main list ..and get the adapter position of each item ...

Comment: How can i find the adapted position from the id of the item?

Comment: i am posting an answer..

Comment: Ok please post the answer thank you

Comment: The question is not very clear. Can you please give us some graphical presentation of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @ReazMurshed I will update the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Hashmap<Integer,Integer> map = new Hashmap<>();
ArrayList<dataset> main_list ; // it contains all objects of dataset

for(int i = 0; i < main_list.size(); i++) {
    int id = main_list.get(i).getId(); // id of the model
    map.put(id, i); // i is the position of adapter
}
```

The map contains the adapter position with the id of each model..

Comment: Thank you. this is working. Will getting the adapted position like this get affected when some items are added or removed from the list?

Comment: of course it will be affected...just call this method again after adding and removing items.. @free_style the final map will contain all the ids with positio

Comment: I didn't know the adapter position just was sequential. Thanks a lot

Comment: yes put this code in a method..like `getMapAgainstId()` and call it multiple times whenever you perform add or remove operation. @free_style